# open in new tab using php

Tags: php, tabs

I want to open the maps in new tap when user click on "view larger map"

```
'gmap'=>array(
                array(
                    '(https*:\/\/maps.google.co.in\/?[^< ]+)',
                    '<iframe width="'.qa_opt('embed_gmap_width').'" height="'.qa_opt('embed_gmap_height').'" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="$1&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="$1&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;output=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>','gmap'
                )
            ),
        );
```

where should I put `target="_blank`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `target="_blank"` inside `<a>` tag. [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

```
<a href="$1&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;output=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left" target="_blank">View Larger Map</a>
```